# This part fell from my car when driving - any idea what it is?

Tags: toyota, part-identification, parts, 4runner

A Part fell off of my 2006 Toyota 4Runner.  Any idea what it is?  It's about 12" x 6".  Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Comment: perhaps part of a heat shield from one of the catalytic converters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2nd that; its a catalytic heat shield. 
Now your catalytic convertor will be able to ignite grass fires when parked more easily.

Comment: Agreed, if it's the bottom shield you could start a forest fire, if it's the top shield it could melt or damage components.

Comment: Bottom line: you'd better fit it back soon.

Comment: They may seem immaterial, but these heat shields are not installed by the manufacturers just to look nice. There are real safety concerns.  Not so much that you cannot drive it somewhere (close) but enough to warrant making an effort to getting it fixed soon.